# struct pointer with pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

If I try to use my struct i got the following errors:

invalid conversion from 'int' to 'Arp::Bit*' [-fpermissive]:

```
input->p2_motorVerticalUp= 1;
```

or 'bool Arp::Bit::value' is private within this context:

```
input->p2_motorVerticalUp->value = 1;
```

Programm:

```
//.hpp

    struct inputPorts
{
public:
    bit *p1_endSwitchHorizontal;
    bit *p2_motorVerticalUp;
    bit *p3_motorVerticalDown;
};


class MyProgram : public ProgramBase, private Loggable<MyProgram>
{
public:
    inputPorts *input;
    bit endSwitchHorizontal;
    bit motorVerticalUp;
    bit motorVerticalDown;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//.cpp

void MyProgram::Execute()
{
    input->p1_endSwitchHorizontal = &endSwitchHorizontal;
    input->p2_motorVerticalUp = &motorVerticalUp;
    input->p3_motorVerticalDown = &motorVerticalDown;



    input->p2_motorVerticalUp= 1;
}
```

How can I allocate a value to endSwitchHorizontal with the struct?

Comment: What is a `bit`?  It's not defined in the code you have posted.  Also `p2_motorVerticalUp` is `bit *` so assigning `1` to a pointer makes no sense.

Comment: Do you really mean allocate or assign?

Comment: bit is boolean. I mean assign.

Comment: @MarcelHinrichs _"bit is boolean"_ So why not using `bool` directly for clarity?

Comment: And this is now clearly a typo question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to set a pointer to a bit (bit*) with an integer of 1.

If you want to set the value of the bit to 1 you have dereference the pointer like this:
`*input->p2_motorVerticalUp = 1;`

Comment: Thanks a lot for this :)